# How to up update in place without entering current changeset ID or hash

Tags: mercurial

So I've got a sample repo:

```
o  2[tip]  default 7cfcb8d177c3
|    Commit #3
|
@  1  default 443465314c87 
|    Commit #2
|
o  0  default 0258e24d8f4e
    initial
```

I want to do an `hg update -C` without changing changesets.

If I do `hg update -C`, it updates me to the tip:

```
@  2[tip]  default 7cfcb8d177c3
|    Commit #3
|
o  1  default 443465314c87 
|    Commit #2
|
o  0  default 0258e24d8f4e
    initial
```

I do not want that.  Now, I can get the behavior I want with either `hg update -C -r 1` or `hg update -C -r 443465314c87`, but that requires me first finding out the revision ID or hash.

Is there any hg command that allows me to `update -C` in place without entering the revision ID or has of the current change set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hg update -C .
```

`.` is the parent of the working directory.  If you're in the middle of a merge, it updates to the first parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to undo all local (uncommited) changes in working dir (as `hg up -C`) without changing changeset, you have to `hg revert -C -a`